# CROSS APPLY on Scalar function

Tags: sql-server, cross-apply

I have this:

```
SELECT
A
,B
,dbo.Func(C)
,dbo.Func(D)
,dbo.Func(E)
,F
FROM abcdef
WHERE
0 = dbo.Func(C) + dbo.Func(D)
```

I have read that this is not good practice because the function is called million of times and it has a bad impact on performance.

I tried to rewrite it with CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT *
 FROM abcdef
  CROSS APPLY dbo.Func(D) as FD
```

but it returns this error:

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.Func'
```

Can I use CROSS APPLY only on TABLE VALUED functions ?

And is CROSS APPLY suitable for scalar functions (converted to table valued function) anyway ? Because on my small performance test CROSS APPLY is a bit slower.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I read that this is not good practice because function is called 'zilion' times and it have bad impact on performance.

While `CROSS APPLY` can be useful in some cases, I don't expect any difference in performance between calling the function in `WHERE` or `CROSS APPLY` in the specific case. If the table has a million rows (and columns `C` and `D` possibly a million different values), a million times the function will be called. How can it be otherwise?

> I tried to rewrite it with `CROSS APPLY`.

Here's how:

```
SELECT
    t.A,
    t.B,
    ca.Fc,
    ca.Fd,
    dbo.Func(t.E) AS Fe
    t.F,
FROM abcdef AS t
  CROSS APPLY 
    ( SELECT
          dbo.Func(t.C) AS Fc, 
          dbo.Func(t.D) AS Fd
    ) AS ca
WHERE 0 = ca.Fc + ca.Fd ;
```

or:

```
SELECT
...
FROM abcdef AS t
  CROSS APPLY 
    ( SELECT
          dbo.Func(t.C) AS Fc, 
          dbo.Func(t.D) AS Fd
      FROM (SELECT NULL) AS dummy
      WHERE 0 = dbo.Func(t.C) + dbo.Func(t.d) 
    ) AS ca ;
```

Again, I don't think this will have any effects on efficiency.

Comment: thank you, about performance, it was ment that if you need to use the output of the function more then one. In another column, for example `SELECT ca.Fc, ca.Fc + ca.Fd`

Answer (score 1):

Scalar udf's may cause your query to run single threaded.

See Ozar's [post](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/11/how-scalar-user-defined-functions-slow-down-queries/) on the matter.